# Github Actions with Azure Devops Pipelines not updating web application

Tags: azure, github, github-actions

So I have a github repo and an azure app service.
I have created a github actions setup which when I run I get this result (no errors)
[image]

However the web app does not update, the main page is the same as before deployment, nothing has changed.
In App Service the GitHub Project value is pointing at the correct project and clicking the link confirms this.

[image]

So I am not sure what is failing to happen, below is my yml file.

name: TestDevelopment
on:
push:
branches:
- development

```
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

jobs:
  build:
    name:  BuildDev
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish testApp.Core/ testApp.Core.csproj --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.1 --output ./publish --runtime win-x86  --self-contained true -p:PublishTrimmed=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true 
        
  unittests:
    needs: build
    name:  Dev Unit Testing
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Unit Tests
      run: dotnet test testApp.Tests --no-restore --verbosity Minimal
      
  webdeploy:
    needs: unittests 
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Azure webapp deploy
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with: 
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.azure  }}
```

Comment: The title of your question and tags appear to be inappropriate. This is a GitHub Actions question that has nothing to do with Azure Pipelines or Azure DevOps as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, I removed the App Service in Azure and then re-created.
Now it works a treat. not sure why but happy as larry now.